# .height() returns 100 whatever the height of the element

Tags: jquery, height, return-value

When i use `.height()` method to get the height of an element, it returns **100** usually whatever the actual height of it.

**CSS CODE**

```
.album_content .album_right .album_thum span { height: 100%; }
```

**Jquery CODE**

```
function center_img(){
    var span_ele = $('.album_content .album_right .album_thum span');
    var img_ele = span_ele.find('img');
    alert(span_ele.height()+','+img_ele.height());
    if(span_ele.height() > img_ele.height()){
        img_ele.css('margin-top',(span_ele.height()-img_ele.height())/2+'px');
    }
}
```

**And see this**

[image]

How can i solve this issue.
Thanks

**The Solution**

When I use `span_ele.length` it returns 21

So the problem was in the selector and now it works Fine!

Comment: can you reproduce this behaviour on a fiddle? www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes! Give us a FIDDLE!!

Comment: That's why you should use block element, unlike SPAN

Comment: I'll give the span element `display: block' and Try again

Comment: @MohamedAref you shouldn't, that's not purpose of SPAN. Use DIVs instead

Comment: I replace **span** with **div** and also didn't work :(

Comment: @MohamedAref How many useless comments until you provide a jsFiddle?!

Answer (score 1):

In your css do this:

```
.album_content .album_right .album_thum span{
   height: 100%;
   display:block; /* <----add this */
}
```

because `span` is an inline level element [checkout here @ MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements)

#### [Demo without display:block](http://jsfiddle.net/2a9DV/)

#### [Demo with display:block](http://jsfiddle.net/2a9DV/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there multiple image tags matching the  `var span_ele = $('.album_content .album_right .album_thum span');` selector, which has a height of 100.

`.height()` gets the :

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the height of every matched element.

[JQuery API Doc](https://api.jquery.com/height/)

Comment: It returns **100** as i give the **span** and the **image** `height:100%`, and I want to get the height in **px** not it **%**

Comment: `.height()` always gets the computed height and not the percentage. See the [JQuery api documentation](https://api.jquery.com/height/)

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Chances are you have multiple matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but your selector `$('.album_content .album_right .album_thum span')` could match multiple elements in your DOM. When you use a method such as `.height()`, it is only going to give you the height of the first matched element. Do you know for certain that your jQuery selector is giving you the height of the element you think it is?

Try doing:

```
alert($('.album_content .album_right .album_thum span').length);
```

This will tell you how many matches there are. If you can be more specific in your query, that would help too.

Comment: It returns **100** as i give the **span** and the **image** `height:100%`, and I want to get the height in **px** not it **%**

Comment: @MohamedAref height() doesn't return pourcentage value but computed style in pixel. Now reproduce your issue in jsfiddle, i guess your issue is coming from inline container

Comment: Why?! I give it `display:block`

Comment: Here is a fiddle showing the multiple matched elements problem: http://jsfiddle.net/428zb/

Comment: It returns 21, so I'll see what is the problem